# Like is not working as expected in update query of join condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-like

Code :

```html
UPDATE elections_ls_2014_stats e
      JOIN `pc-details` p
      ON ( e.name LIKE CONCAT('%' ,p.candidate_name ,'%') )
SET    e.pc_details_id = p.id  WHERE  p.year =  '2014'
AND p.`candidate_results_position` ='1' AND e.pc_details_id IS NULL
```

Here its not working as expected 
eg :Dr Pandula Ravindra Babu    AND  Pandula Ravindra Babu

this is one of the case where this condition is not working as expected , means update query is not working .

but in select statement I am getting the result for the above cases .(Dr Pandula Ravindra Babu    AND  Pandula Ravindra Babu)

code :

```html
SELECT pd.id AS pc_details_id, el.id AS election_2014_id, pd.candidate_name, el.name
FROM  `pc-details` pd,  `elections_ls_2014_stats` el
WHERE pd.`year` LIKE  '2014'
AND pd.`candidate_results_position` =1
AND pd.candidate_name LIKE CONCAT(  '%', el.name,  '%' )
```

Am I doing anything wrong in the update query .

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UPDATE` query the `LIKE` expression is the opposite way around to the way it is in your `SELECT` query. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE elections_ls_2014_stats e
      JOIN `pc-details` p
      ON p.candidate_name LIKE CONCAT('%', e.name,  '%') 
SET    e.pc_details_id = p.id  WHERE  p.year =  '2014'
AND p.`candidate_results_position` ='1' AND e.pc_details_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes it works for me but why you alternate the like condition . could you please explain me ?

Comment: @sradha I just made it the same as the one in your `SELECT` query, which you said was working.

Comment: Okay got it..Thank u

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
  UPDATE elections_ls_2014_stats e
          JOIN `pc-details` p
    SET    e.pc_details_id = p.id  
    WHERE  p.year =  '2014'
    AND p.`candidate_results_position` ='1' AND e.pc_details_id IS NULL and  e.name LIKE CONCAT('%' ,p.candidate_name ,'%')
```

Comment: No its not working for me :( , same result as prevoius